# Don't understand which command is used in video during modeling

Tags: modeling

At the 2:50 mark in this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPWkswbRqQ, a vertice is selected and then becomes a face. It happens really fast and I would like to know which command is used here?
Is there any clue in the interface that I can see what was pressed? The keys aren't logged onscreen unfortunately..

Comment: On YouTube you can pause the video and use comma and period to move single frames in either direction.  You should be able to see the operator panel in the bottom left.

Comment: @AllenSimpson: why didn't you say that 1 year ago?!? i found out that some weeks ago...and it would have been so useful.....

Answer (score 1):

It was the bevel command, so another mystery solved..